# Android Firestore set limit to 1 vote per user

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-togglebutton

I'm creating my first app from scratch which is a forum app on android and I've gotten to the upvoting/downvoting part of it.

I have it set up to where my users can upvote downvote (similar to StackOverflow) however I don't know how to limit it to one vote per user.

I'm using Firebase-Firestore as a DB.

I have the upvote and downvote toggle buttons set to update the score in firestore on a button click listener in with their respective selector `item.xml` for each.

Could anyone shed any light on an approach to limiting a user to one vote per answer per user similar to stack overflow?

Any and all help is appreciated.

> edit

Current Code before trying provided answers.

AnswerAdapter

```
public class AnswerAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Answer, AnswerAdapter.AnswerHolder> {

    private QuestionAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener;
    private Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG = "AnswerAdapter";

    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See {@link
     * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */

    public AnswerAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Answer> options) {

        super(options);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AnswerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.answer_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new AnswerHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AnswerAdapter.AnswerHolder answerHolder, final int position, @NonNull final Answer model) {

        answerHolder.answerItemTextView.setText(model.getAnswer());
        answerHolder.answerAuthorTextView.setText(model.getAuthor());
        answerHolder.answerTimeStampTextView.setText(model.getTimestamp());
        answerHolder.answerScoreTextView.setText(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).get("answerScore").toString());

        answerHolder.mAnswerUpVoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO: 2019-07-26 check order of operations. seems to go through upvote and then also through downvote unchecking state
                if (answerHolder.mAnswerUpVoteButton.isChecked()){

                    answerUpVote(answerHolder, position, model);
                } else {
//                    answerDownVote(answerHolder, position, model);
                }
            }
        });

public class AnswerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView answerItemTextView;
        TextView answerScoreTextView;
        ToggleButton answerCheckMark;
        TextView answerAuthorTextView;
        TextView answerTimeStampTextView;
        ToggleButton mAnswerUpVoteButton;
        ToggleButton mAnswerDownVoteButton;


        public AnswerHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            answerItemTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerItemTextViewId);
            answerScoreTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionScoreId);
            answerCheckMark = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerCheckMarkId);
            answerAuthorTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerAuthorTextViewId);
            answerTimeStampTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerTimeStampTextViewId);
            mAnswerUpVoteButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerUpVoteId);
            mAnswerDownVoteButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerDownVoteId);

            mContext = itemView.getContext();

        }

    }

private void answerUpVote(@NonNull final AnswerAdapter.AnswerHolder answerHolder, final int position, @NonNull final Answer model) {
        final String answerScoreFBValue = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).get("answerScore").toString();
        final String answerFirebaseIdString = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).get("answerFirebaseId").toString();
//        Toast.makeText(mContext, "upvote button clicked " + answerScoreFBValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final CollectionReference answerCollectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Answers");
        final DocumentReference answerDocRef = answerCollectionRef.document(answerFirebaseIdString);


        answerDocRef.update("answerScore", FieldValue.increment(1)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            //                answerRef.document().update("answerscore", answerScoreTestInt).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: answerScore incremented");
//                answerHolder.answerScoreTextView.setText("testing");

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: answerScore was not incremented", e);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Answer.java**

```
package com.example.stairmaster.models;

public class Answer {

    private String answer;
    private String comment; 
    private String timestamp;
    private int answerScore;
    private String author;
    private String answerFirebaseId;
    private String parentQuestionId;


    public Answer(String answer, String timeStamp, String author, String parentQuestionId, int answerScore) {

        this.answer = answer;
        this.timestamp = timeStamp;
        this.answerScore = answerScore;
        this.author = author;
        this.parentQuestionId = parentQuestionId;
    }

    public Answer () {
        // public no-arg constructor needed
    }

    public String getAnswerFirebaseId() {
        return answerFirebaseId;
    }

    public void setAnswerFirebaseId(String answerFirebaseId) {
        this.answerFirebaseId = answerFirebaseId;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public int getAnswerScore() {
        return answerScore;
    }

    public void setAnswerScore(int answerScore) {
        answerScore = answerScore;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getParentQuestionId() {
        return parentQuestionId;
    }

    public void setParentQuestionId(String parentQuestionId) {
        this.parentQuestionId = parentQuestionId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Share some code so we can better help

Comment: @treewallie, will do later. Currently at work atm.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @Treewallie, added code for you

Comment: @AlexMamo, not yet. I wont be able to tackle it until tomorrow or later on this week unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider modifying your database tables in your firebase database to look like the following.

```
user_votes:
  - userid: 1234232 // A sample user id for your user
    - forumid: 8769765 // The id of the forum or blog
      - upvote: 1 // Number of upvotes in that specific forum/blog
      - downvote: 0 // Number indicates the downvote to that forum/blog
    - forumid: 1233432 
      - upvote: 1 
      - downvote: 0 
    - forumid: 8712169767 
      - upvote: 0 
      - downvote: 1
```

And the other table which keeps the record of upvotes/downvotes for a specific forum/blog might look like the following.

```
all_votes:
  - forumid: 8769765 // The id of the forum or blog
    - upvote: 9876 // Number of upvotes in that specific forum/blog
    - downvote: 123 // Number indicates the downvote to that forum/blog
  - forumid: 1233432 
    - upvote: 87 
    - downvote: 12 
  - forumid: 8712169767 
    - upvote: 112 
    - downvote: 10
```

Now, based on these two tables, you can easily decide if you are going to issue a `setValue` command in your `all_votes` table for a forum id. If the user is found to have issued an upvote already, then make the application logic in such a way that it does not issue another upvote in the `all_votes` table for that specific user.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for your suggestion i'll look into giving your method a shot. I am not familiar with the 'setValue' command. That gives me some homework to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a similar thing and the way I did it was using a local room database. So first, it checks the local database to see if the user can vote. If they can, then it sends a request to firestore to update the associated field. I am also using RxKotlin and wrapping the returned Task<> (from the request to firestore) into an observable. If the observable completes without any error, then it updates the local database. If it fails, then it doesn't do anything. I am sure there are other methods out there but this is how I chose to do it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i had never known about local room db until now. i'll see if i can look into it and give it a shot. Any idea if it plays well with Firestore or not?

Comment: It plays well if you implement it correctly. I wrap everything into an observable (anything that is returned from both local and remote databases). Reaz's method seems excellent as well but then that is extra read requests for firestore. But my method will be more complicated since you have to setup the local database.

Comment: I had another idea, but its probably very primitive. I could add a list of users votes to the answer model. for example, if a user upvotes, their unique user id would be added to the list. Doing this would allow me to keep track who has upvoted or downvoted. I could make it so the upvote or downvote is a button click listener and checks the answer's list of people who have voted. If there is a match, then it would not let that user vote twice. This list could be held in firestore. This sounds similar to your approach although it would only be using Firestore. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it would work, but if you use a local database, you don't have to make that extra write/read requests (saves you usuage/money on firestore). Also extra network calls are just more points of failure. But in the end, its up to you and that method will work.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've been looking into it for the past couple days. Theres not very many instances of people using firestore with a local room db. Did you by chance find any good examples of people using both you could point me to?

Comment: THe problem if the app is cracked a hacker can send infinite upvotes to the server